# Magento 2: Run reindexer using REST API

Tags: api, rest-api, reindex

Is any one having tried to create REST API so using custom API one can trigger re-indexing?

which method do i have to mention in webapi.xml file as this is purely AREA::ADMIN activitiy. currently tried with POST (create) and PUT (Update).
Below is the `webapi.xml`

```
<route url="/V1/customapi" method="POST">
        <service class="Sark\CustomApi\Api\CustomRepositoryInterface" method="create"/>
        <resources>
             <resource ref="self"/>
        </resources>
    </route>
```

Further, for controller do i have to create API folder and interface mandatory or it is optional.

Index pro-grammatically code is as follows:

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $indexerCollectionFactory = $objectManager->get("\Magento\Indexer\Model\Indexer\CollectionFactory");
    $indexerFactory = $objectManager->get("\Magento\Indexer\Model\IndexerFactory");

    $indexerCollection = $indexerCollectionFactory->create();
    $allIds = $indexerCollection->getAllIds();
    foreach ($allIds as $id) {
        $indexer = $indexerFactory->create()->load($id);
        $indexer->reindexAll();
    }
```

It would be good if any other API is also there to do the same magic (except the direct custom script file).

Ref.: http://codetheatres.com/magento/creating-custom-api-in-magento2-using-rest-protocol/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using API indexing is not a good Idea.

***As Indexing run on the command line and it takes much usage on memory & time, So it, not a good idea.***

If you want then change the *indexing status of each indexing to **pending** state* and Magento cron automatically do indexing as it was in pending. That is the best Solution.

Create `di.xml` at `app/code/Sark/CustomApi/etc/` and where you will  define a model class  **CustomRepository** at `app/code/Sark/CustomApi/Model/` which overrides `Sark\CustomApi\Api\CustomRepositoryInterface`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Sark\CustomApi\Api\CustomRepositoryInterface" type="Sark\CustomApi\Model\CustomRepository"/>
</config>
```

And `CustomRepository.php` code is

```
<?php

namespace Sark\CustomApi\Model;

class CustomRepository implements Sark\CustomApi\Api\CustomRepositoryInterface
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Indexer\IndexerRegistry
     */
    private $indexerRegistry;
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Indexer\Model\ResourceModel\Indexer\State\CollectionFactory
     */
    private $stateCollectionFactory;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Indexer\IndexerRegistry $indexerRegistry,
        \Magento\Indexer\Model\ResourceModel\Indexer\State\CollectionFactory $stateCollectionFactory
    ) {
        $this->indexerRegistry = $indexerRegistry;
        $this->stateCollectionFactory = $stateCollectionFactory;
    }

    public function create()
    {
        $indexerStates = $this->stateCollectionFactory->create();
        foreach ($indexerStates->getItems() as $indexerState) {
            $indexerState->getIndexerId();
            $indexer = $this->indexerRegistry->get($indexerState->getIndexerId());
            if ($indexer->getId() && !$indexer->isWorking()) {
                $indexer->setScheduled(true);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Accepted! many thanks for the answer. yes i agreed it will use much resources at server end and it should run on `CLI`. this will help a lot.