# Magento 2: Call Controller method from Model

Tags: magento2, api, controllers, model

How to call the controller method from model?

Or

How to programmatically reindexing using API?

---

Here is my code.Below code gives me error like below.

> {
>       "messages": {
>           "error": [
>               {
>                   "code": 500,
>                   "message": "Fatal Error: 'Class Inchoo\Hello\Model\Hello contains 1 abstract method and must
>   therefore be declared abstract or implement the remaining methods
>   (Magento\Framework\App\ActionInterface::execute)' in
>   'C:\new\xampp\htdocs\ChoiceWholesale\app\code\Inchoo\Hello\Model\Hello.php'
>   on line 5",
>                   "trace": "Trace is not available."
>               }
>           ]
>       } }

```
<?php
namespace Inchoo\Hello\Model;
use Inchoo\Hello\Api\HelloInterface;

class Hello extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action implements HelloInterface
{

    protected $indexFactory;
    protected $indexCollection;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Indexer\Model\IndexerFactory $indexFactory,
        \Magento\Indexer\Model\Indexer\CollectionFactory $indexCollection
    )
    {
        $this->indexFactory = $indexFactory;
        $this->indexCollection = $indexCollection;
        return parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function name() {

        $indexerCollection = $this->indexCollection->create();
        $indexids = $indexerCollection->getAllIds();

        foreach ($indexids as $indexid)
        {
          $indexidarray = $this->indexFactory->create()->load($indexid);

          //If you want reindex all use this code.
           $indexidarray->reindexAll($indexid);

          //If you want to reindex one by one, use this code
           $indexidarray->reindexRow($indexid);

           echo "Reindexing Id :: " .$indexid ."<br>"; 

        }
        echo "Reindexing Completed";
        exit;

    }
}
```

Comment: Your question is confusing what you actually want to do?

Comment: Check this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/270845/magento-2-run-reindexer-using-rest-api

Comment: Why do you want to call controller method in model ?

Comment: @Sumit after using your code Give me an error  like https://prnt.sc/p9qqgj

Answer (score 0):

Using API indexing is not a good Idea.

**As Indexing run on the command line and it takes much usage on memory & time, So it, not a good idea.**

If you want then change the indexing status of each indexing to **pending** state and Magento cron automatically do indexing as it was in pending. That is the best Solution.

Create `di.xml` at `app/code/Sark/CustomApi/etc/` and where you will define a model class **CustomRepository** at `app/code/Sark/CustomApi/Model/` which overrides `Sark\CustomApi\Api\CustomRepositoryInterface`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Sark\CustomApi\Api\CustomRepositoryInterface" type="Sark\CustomApi\Model\CustomRepository"/>
</config>
```

And `CustomRepository.php` code is

```
<?php

namespace Sark\CustomApi\Model;

class CustomRepository implements Sark\CustomApi\Api\CustomRepositoryInterface
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Indexer\IndexerRegistry
     */
    private $indexerRegistry;
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Indexer\Model\ResourceModel\Indexer\State\CollectionFactory
     */
    private $stateCollectionFactory;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Indexer\IndexerRegistry $indexerRegistry,
        \Magento\Indexer\Model\ResourceModel\Indexer\State\CollectionFactory $stateCollectionFactory
    ) {
        $this->indexerRegistry = $indexerRegistry;
        $this->stateCollectionFactory = $stateCollectionFactory;
    }

    public function create()
    {
        $indexerStates = $this->stateCollectionFactory->create();
        foreach ($indexerStates->getItems() as $indexerState) {
            $indexerState->getIndexerId();
            $indexer = $this->indexerRegistry->get($indexerState->getIndexerId());
            if ($indexer->getId() && !$indexer->isWorking()) {
                $indexer->setScheduled(true);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Con you please describe the **$indexer->setScheduled(true);** line? Why it is used?

Comment: It's give me error.https://prnt.sc/p9qqgj

Comment: Error is from Inchoo sir not from my code.
You need to put one code at time.

Comment: In Which line , How to solve this error?

Comment: You need to check where you put this code and remove it and use at a time one code only.

Comment: i have used same code as above you gave me.